# Magento 2: Cart Price Rules - Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y) is Not Working

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules, rules

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.12

I have followed the below one, as well other tutorials.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-setup-buy-x-get-y-free-in-magento-2.html

Still, it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please create cart price rule and for action tab check below screen shot :

[image: action]

Now please add to cart product with qty 2 and apply this coupon code now you will get one product price as a discount.

Actually there is no any facility that magento give buy 1 get 1 free automatic so we have to add product with qty 2 and apply rule then we get the discount.

Comment: I  have done these things but discount not showing coupon applied but not discount showing